# JQuery with "audio" element in HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to JQuery, this is a basic question, and I do not why the following code does not work. Please help me to figure it out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>

        function test()
        {
            var audios=$("#audio1");
            alert(audios.volume);  //This line does not work, it returns "undefined"
            audios.volume=0.5; //This line does not work
            // audios.hide();  - This works fine
        }
    </script>
    <title>This is a test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
                <input type="button" value="Test" onclick="test()">
                <audio id="audio1" controls autoplay>
                    <source  src="http://zz.qz828.net/06/three.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
                    Your browser does not support the audio element.
                </audio>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Have no idea why these two lines does not work:

```
alert(audios.volume);  //This line does not work
audios.volume=0.5; //This line does not work
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to set the volume property to the dom element, `$("#audio1")` returns a jQuery object which does not have the `volume` property.

So you need to access the dom element from the jQuery object and then set the property or use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to set the property value

```
audios[0].volume=0.5;
//or audios.prop('volume', 0.5);
```

Comment: Looks like there is a difference between jquery object vs DOM object, right?

Comment: @JackZhang it returns a [jQuery Object](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/) not a dom element

Comment: @JackZhang there is very little common between them

Comment: Got it, this is kind of annoying, need to understand more basic concept of JQuery, I was assuming that JQuery returns exactly the DOM object directly, so I can use is for free.